# How to reference Django Rest Framework Router URLs when Django is not serving the root of the web server

Tags: python, django, url, django-rest-framework

I had my API working well, but with DJango serving the entire document root, behind Apache.  The team has decided they have some pieces that they want to serve out of the root (non-API) via apache directly, so I'm pushing the DJango WSGI reference from / to /api.

From:

```
WSGIScriptAlias / /opt/org/myproj/myapp/wsgi.py
```

To:

```
WSGIScriptAlias /api/ /opt/org/myproj/myapp/wsgi.py
```

The main urls.py went from:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
                       url(r'^api/', include(router.urls)),
```

to:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
                       url(r'^', include(router.urls)),
```

The problem is, when I hit the webserver at /api/ I do get the router URLs, but when I try to hit one of the actual URLs, I'm getting a 404.  It's not actually dealing with any of the sub-URL references.

Hitting /api/ correctly gives:

```
{
address: "https://172.17.100.7/api/address/",
chassis: "https://172.17.100.7/api/chassis/",
configurationfile: "https://172.17.100.7/api/configurationfile/",
job: "https://172.17.100.7/api/job/",
node: "https://172.17.100.7/api/node/",
operatingsystem: "https://172.17.100.7/api/operatingsystem/"
}
```

Hitting /api/address gives:

```
Not Found

The requested URL /api/address/ was not found on this server.

Apache/2.2.22 (Debian) Server at 172.17.100.7 Port 443
```

Can someone provide some insight into how the URLs are supposed to be referenced in such a case?  I thought this was going to be a pretty simple change, but I'm at a loss.

EDIT: Here's the full apache config.

```
WSGIScriptAlias /api/ /opt/org/myproj/myapp/wsgi.py

<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
  DocumentRoot /var/www

  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
  RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>

  ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
  DocumentRoot /opt/org/myproj/root

  <Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
  </Directory>

  <Directory /opt/org/myproj/root/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
  </Directory>

  Alias /repo /opt/myorg/myproj/repo/

  <Directory /opt/hp/moonshot/repo/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
  </Directory>

  ErrorLog /opt/myorg/myproj/logs/error.log
  LogLevel warn
  CustomLog /opt/myorg/myproj/logs/access.log combined

  <Directory /opt/myorg/myproj/myapp>
    <Files wsgi.py>
      Order deny,allow
      Allow from all
    </Files>
  </Directory>

  # SSL Options
  SSLEngine on
  SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
  SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
  <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
    SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
  </FilesMatch>
  BrowserMatch "MSIE [2-6]"     nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown     downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0
  BrowserMatch "MSIE [17-9]" ssl-unclean-shutdown
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Can you paste your apache config?

Comment: Added apache config in edit above.  The parts served by Apache (document root, /repo) work AOK, which is what points me to something about the urls.py entry.

Comment: Have you tried adding `FORCE_SCRIPT_NAME='/api'`(no trailing slash) to your settings.py and restarting apache?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From memory, use:

```
WSGIScriptAlias /api/ /opt/org/myproj/myapp/wsgi.py/api/
```

Put your Django stuff back to how it was.

This will only intercept sub url of '/api/' but the WSGI application will still think it is at the root of the site.

Comment: Just be aware that you can do this more than once for different sub URLs if need be and it should still only result in one sub interpreter instance running your code even though multiple WSGIScriptAlias directives. Obviously just make sure the URL part attached at end of WSGI script file path matches the URL mount point you are intercepting.